# Save as an int from charAt

Tags: java

E.g:

```
public static void test() {
    int x = 0 ;
    String line = "A24 ASD 46" ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < line.length() ; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(i))) {
            int number = line.charAt(i) ;
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

"x" is printing the ASCII value of a char, and not the element of String at index "i" ! How to print the element in index of a String ?

Comment: You only print the numerical chars (`if(Character.isDigit(...))`), and you are printing their ASCII value, which will not be their actual value. What did you expect to get?

Comment: Just print directly `System.out.println(line.charAt(i));` don't convert them to `int`

Comment: I wanted to store and than to print that value !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need int value here, there is [`getNumericValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) for this case:

```
int number = Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(i))
```

But if you want just print all numbers from the source string, you don't have to convert `char` to `int` as [@Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934428/save-as-an-int-from-charat/54934505#comment96633330_54934428) mentioned. Just do `System.out.println(line.charAt(i));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find digits using streams:

```
String line = "A24 ASD 46";
line.chars()
    .filter(Character::isDigit)
    .mapToObj(Character::toString)
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

will print 2446.